# Get Count of related records in sailsjs

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have an artist model that has a collection of songs.  I am not populating the related songs in the blueprints config, but I would like to at least get a count back so I know how many songs are on each artist.  Here is what my simple artist model looks like:

module.exports = {

attributes: {
      name:{
          type: 'string',
          required: true
      },
      songs:{
          collection: 'song',
          via: 'artist'
      }
  }
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a count back you will have two options.

Option A.) Run a second query

```
Song.count({artist:artist}).exec(/*...*/)
```

Option B.) Keep a count value in the artist model that increases / decreases as songs are added / removed. This is probably your best option as it will request the least stress on the DB in those cases where artists are being scanned / queried more than songs are being added.

Comment: if I only knew about it beforehand! Now I am forced to change the ORM